# Open a website from javascript in my own page

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I did a web application which have some html pages:

1. Main
2. Results.

In the main page I allow the user to search for something from Youtube.
and then I want to show the Youtube results in the Results page.

To do that, I wrote a function in javaScript in the Results page

```
function loadContent()
{
  window.location.href = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query = " + userSearch;
}
```

which I call when the page is load () event.

But it opens a new page in the browser instead of showing the results in my page.. 
why?

Comment: Putting this as a comment because it doesn't tell you how to do what you want, but that is just how `window.location.href` works.  It is basically a redirect, same as if you clicked on a link. I would think that the solution to your problem would be to use ajax.

Answer (score 2):

try putting an iFrame in result page.

then Update the source

```
$("#iframeId").attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query = " + userSearch);
```

Comment: thanks, but youtube don't allow to display their content within an Iframe, but +1 for the suggestion

Comment: then you can try putting the embedd-code of youtube in your html.

Comment: I know, but this isn't answer my problem. I want to show the user the results page in my application, instead the browser will open a new webpage